# Tizen studio 2: application installation failure

Tags: certificate, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

I have just installed Tizen Studio 2.0 and I was trying to update my old application  (version wearable 2.2) with new features.
The target device is a Samsung "Gear 2" (not "Gear S2").
By means of the package manager I installed both the Samsung certificate and the Samsung wearable extension.
I removed all the old certificates and acquired a new one via the certificate manager (Samsung option). The new certificate results active.
From the device manager/file explorer I selected "permit to install applications". The result was en error and an invitation to create and activate a Samsung certificate.  Exactly what I had done previoulsy!!!!!!

Trying to install the app via debugger the result was:

```
 [Initializing the launch environment...]  
        RDS: On  
        Target information: SM-R380  
        Application information: Id(Z8KnFDT3ds.ride), Package Name(Z8KnFDT3ds),
      Project Name(ride)
    [Transferring the package...]
        Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp/ride.wgt  
    [Installing the package...]  
    path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/ride.wgt  
    processing result : FATAL_ERROR [61] failed  
    spend time for pkgcmd is [94]ms  
    cmd_ret:61  
        An exception occurred  
    (Installing the package... > Fail)  
    An exception occurred  
    Unexpected stop progress...  
    (9.763 sec)"
```

I have already tried (uselessly) to:

1. regenerate the .medata file,
2. to create a new the workspace,
3. to reinstall Tizen 2.0.,
4. to create a new certificate,
5. to install the wgt via sdb.

The time and the date on the Gear 2 are correctly synchronized with my host computer (OS Windows 10).

I noticed an anomaly in my Gear 2 DUID (PB+hcyFaLdbqjuVe+Gcn4vBlSYw=)
Considering what reported at the link: http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/getting-certificates/permit  the DUID should be in any case preceded by a #1.0 or #2.0. This is not true in my case.
By changing manually the DUID to: 1.0#PB+hcyFaLdbqjuVe+Gcn4vBlSYw= a certficate is apparently correctly uploaded on the target even if the FATAL error 61 persits.

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have been having insurmountable problems with SDK 2.0 as well.  Eventually I decided to roll back to the previous version but was struggling to find out how or where to get it.  I got a response from the Tizen support team with the following instructions.

1. Launch Package Manager
2. click the "Configuration" icon in the top right corner of the Package Manager window.
3. Turn OFF the "Auto Update" feature
4. You will be able to see the list of previous versions of Tizen Studio. Select your desired version and click "OK"
5. This will prompt you that its going to update the previous version. please follow the UI prompt to uninstall this version and install the previous version.

This may or may not work for you.